# Release Management Server Installation Issue - object already exists

Tags: ms-release-management

I am getting the following error while configuring RM server: `Object Already exists` in Windows Server 2008 R2 enterprise. Please find the log.

```
I, 2014/10/29, 08:18:40.108, Variable : Key = DefaultLogin, Value = GAP-RELEASE\BuildUser
I, 2014/10/29, 08:18:40.124, Variable : Key = DefaultAdmin, Value = GAP-RELEASE\BuildUser
I, 2014/10/29, 08:18:40.124, Variable : Key = DatabaseName, Value = ReleaseManagement
I, 2014/10/29, 08:18:40.124, Variable : Key = DefaultLocalService, Value = NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
I, 2014/10/29, 08:18:53.384, Database ReleaseManagement, version 12.0.30723.0 was installed successfully.
I, 2014/10/29, 08:18:53.399, Created Release Management database.
E, 2014/10/29, 08:18:53.462, Received Exception : System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Object already exists.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._CreateCSP(CspParameters param, Boolean randomKeyContainer, SafeProvHandle& hProv)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeyPairHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, Int32 dwKeySize, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.GetKeyPair()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.CommonConfiguration.Helpers.CryptoHelper.ConfigureServerCryptoKey(String serverName, String databaseName)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.Configure(ConfigurationUpdatePack updatePack, DelegateStatusUpdate statusListener)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
I, 2014/10/29, 08:18:53.462, Work completed for GetConfiguration() call : got out of turn error
E, 2014/10/29, 08:18:53.462, Object already exists.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the samen issue. A lot people forward to this solution: http://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2014/11/04/%E2%80%9CObject-already-exists%E2%80%9D-error-during-Release-Management-server-configuration.aspx

That didn't work me and I finally let the infra team restore the machine. That fixed the problem for me.

In my case the database server was on another machine and I kept all my release paths and templates.

The only thing I had to reconfigure was the IIS path: http://localhost:1000/releasemanagement

Answer (score -1):

Make your release management service account a local administrator on the Release Management server.

Update: I recently ran into this issue at a client. The service account was a local admin, but the account didn't have the necessary permissions to the Machine Keys folder (C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys). For some reason, I couldn't apply the permissions -- I received an Access Denied message, even with a fully privileged account.

I ended up solving it as follows:

1. Take ownership of the MachineKeys folder with the service user
2. Give full read/write permission to the service user
3. Reset ownership of the folder to the SYSTEM account